# Javascript show / hide elements

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

1. I have a hidden text area (which is defined as **hidden** with bootstrap)
2. I have a dropdown which has 2 options.
3. If I select 1st option, textarea should be **shown**.
4. If I select 2nd option, textarea should **disappear**.

Here are my codes and I don't know where I go wrong :

```
function OnSelectedIndexChange(){

    var getDropDown = document.getElementById("myDropDownID");
    var getDropDownSelectedItemValue = getDropDown.options[getDropDown.selectedIndex].text;

    if(getDropDownSelectedItemValue == 'Yes'){
        document.getElementById("myTextAreaID").style.display = 'block';
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById("myTextAreaID").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE:

Added jsfiddle link : [jsfiddle.net/wy562fk8/1](http://jsfiddle.net/wy562fk8/1) but i am using blade templating, so you can't be able to see any output.

Comment: please post your html as well, and create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: How/where are you calling `OnSelectedIndexChange`?

Comment: How exactly is it "defined as hidden with bootstrap"?

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/wy562fk8/1/ but i am using blade templating, so you can't be able to see any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `onchange` function.

```
document.getElementById("myDropDownID").onchange = function {
  if(document.getElementById("myDropDownID").value == 'Yes'){
        document.getElementById("myTextAreaID").style.display = 'block';
    }

    else{
        document.getElementById("myTextAreaID").style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this too, I don't know but i am not able to do it still.

Answer (score 1):

Might be the reason you are doing

```
 var getDropDownSelectedItemValue = getDropDown.options[getDropDown.selectedIndex].text;
```

instead of

```
 var getDropDownSelectedItemValue = getDropDown.options[getDropDown.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: can you fiddle the output instead of blade template, also try removing hidden class from textarea as it might be using visibility css